# How do NSBundle pathForResource:ofType: and UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: handle scale and device modifiers?

Tags: ios, uiimage, retina-display, nsbundle

In my iOS resource folder, I have the images:

```
foo~iphone.png
foo@2x~iphone.png
foo~ipad.png
foo@2x~ipad.png
```

I load them with:

```
NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
```

Experimentally:

On the iPhone, `filename` is `/path/to/bundle/foo~iphone.png`, and on the retina iPhone, it loads the `@2x` version.

On the iPad, `filename` is `/path/to/bundle/foo~ipad.png`, and on the retina iPad, it loads the `@2x` version.

That is, it loads the image I'd hope, but `pathForResource` handles the device modifier, and `imageWithContentsOfFile` handles the scale modifier.

I'd like to know why. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of `pathForResource` says nothing about device modifiers, and the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of `imageWithContentsOfFile` says nothing about scale modifiers.

Is there separate documentation that indicates precisely what each function does?

Comment: What value is your fileName string holding when you set a bp on the UIImage line? In other words how do you know the scaling is happening within the imageWithContentsOfFile?

Comment: @MarkM, as I said, on the iPhone, `filename` is `/path/to/bundle/foo~iphone.png`, so I know it's only getting the name of the non-@2x version. When this name is fed into `UIImage`, I get the hi-res version.

Answer (score 14):

The explanation for `imageWithContentsOfFile` is in [related documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW1), not in the `UIImage` documentation itself:

> On devices with high-resolution screens, the imageNamed:, imageWithContentsOfFile:, and initWithContentsOfFile: methods automatically looks for a version of the requested image with the @2x modifier in its name. If it finds one, it loads that image instead. If you do not provide a high-resolution version of a given image, the image object still loads a standard-resolution image (if one exists) and scales it during drawing.
>
> When it loads an image, a UIImage object automatically sets the size and scale properties to appropriate values based on the suffix of the image file. For standard resolution images, it sets the scale property to 1.0 and sets the size of the image to the image’s pixel dimensions. For images with the @2x suffix in the filename, it sets the scale property to 2.0 and halves the width and height values to compensate for the scale factor. These halved values correlate correctly to the point-based dimensions you need to use in the logical coordinate space to render the image."

I don't know which documentation explains the behavior of `pathForResource`.

Comment: Please quote from the documentation. I can't seem to find anywhere in either the overall `UIImage` documentation or the specific `imageWithContentsOfFile` documentation that talks about scaling.

Comment: And I'm also interested in why `pathForResource` handles the device modifier.

Comment: My answer has been updated to include quotes from the documentation talking about the different UIImage methods and why their actions do what they do. There is also discussion about the device modifier in there. If you are looking for more information on this I would recommend the WWDC videos as they provide examples and implementation of all these techniques.

Comment: Thanks; I edited your answer a bit - feel free to tweak it if you don't like it. Any thoughts on the `pathForResource` issue? (I'm really looking for documentation, not videos of examples.)

Comment: I'll search around and see what I can find. I agree, Apple has a tendency to offer much more in depth explanations and techniques of their processes during WWDC than in their actual documentation. This has been a common theme of theirs since day 1 of the App Store in my experience. Although watching their videos can be a time consuming process I have definitely learned advanced techniques as well as good habits by watching their examples and following their logic path. Some examples are complex just to show different techniques to reach an end result even if it may not be the "best" solution.